# How to save a Keras model, when the handle of a KerasLayer is not a string

Tags: python, tf.keras

I'm writing a model that uses BERT as an encoder. Using the preprocessor directly from tfhub worked just fine. But trying to customize it by separating the tokenizer and bert_pack_inputs  gives me a warning that the model cannot be saved properly.

here's a code snippet

```py
preprocessor = hub.load(tfhub_handle_preprocess)
    
tokenize = hub.KerasLayer(preprocessor.tokenize)
tokenized_text = tokenize(text_input)

bert_pack_inputs = hub.KerasLayer(
    preprocessor.bert_pack_inputs,
    arguments=dict(seq_length=input_sequence_length))
encoder_inputs = bert_pack_inputs([tokenized_text])

encoder = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_encoder,
                         trainable=True, name='BERT_encoder')
```

and here's the warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model failed to serialize as JSON. Ignoring... Can only generate a valid config for `hub.KerasLayer(handle, ...)`that uses a string `handle`.
```

loading the model afterwards also yields an error:

```
Option 2:
  Positional arguments (2 total):
    * [RaggedTensorSpec(TensorShape([None, None, None]), tf.int32, 2, tf.int64)]
    * False
  Keyword arguments: {}
```

I tried to look up the error online and I think it's because of the two KerasLayers that take the preprocessor.tokenize and  preprocessor.bert_pack_inputs instead of a string as parameters. But i'm not sure how to fix it. any tips ? Thank you in advance :)